# Manually create span with start and end timestamps - OpenTelemetry Python

Tags: python, open-telemetry

I am trying to trace the execution of a task in Celery through the Publisher -> Queue -> Consumer lifecycle. I am using OpenTelemetry 1.16.0 in Python 3.9.15 in order to instrument the application. I already know how to propagate a trace through the Queue as described in the answers to this stackoverflow question.

[OpenTelemetry Python - How to instanciate a new span as a child span for a given trace_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68530363/opentelemetry-python-how-to-instanciate-a-new-span-as-a-child-span-for-a-given)

In addition to propagating the trace through the Queue I want to create a span in the trace for the time spent on the Queue. Right now, that period of time just appears as a gap in the trace as viewed in Grafana Tempo. I should be able to manually create this span assuming that I have trace id, parent span id, timestamp for when task is added to Queue, and timestamp for when task is taken from Queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [`start_span`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/blob/c84ba9483ca9b4642904b69897f931813d60cff0/opentelemetry-sdk/src/opentelemetry/sdk/trace/__init__.py#L1047-L1057) to create your own spans. It accepts `start_time` (or uses current if not provided). Like wise, there is an [`end`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/blob/c84ba9483ca9b4642904b69897f931813d60cff0/opentelemetry-sdk/src/opentelemetry/sdk/trace/__init__.py#L884) to end the span which takes the `end_time` to indicate when span ended.

It would look like this

```py
import time

from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import (
    ConsoleSpanExporter,
)
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import BatchExportSpanProcessor

trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider())
trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(
    BatchExportSpanProcessor(ConsoleSpanExporter())
)



tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)

span = tracer.start_span("foo", start_time=...)

...

span.end(end_time=...)
```

Comment: yes, thank you. and btw, `start_time` and `end_time` are timestamps in nanoseconds (i.e. integer with 19 digits).